# No sé cómo obtener el nombre para un Select

Tags: java

He realizado un método que me selecciona la id a través del nombre. El problema es que tal y como lo tengo me da un nombre vacío y por lo tanto me da error:

```
     public int getIdArtista(){

    Conexion conexion=new Conexion();
    ArtistaVO artistaVO=new ArtistaVO();
    int id=0;

    try{
        String consultaSql="SELECT ArtistId from artist where Name=?";
        PreparedStatement sqlArtistaId=conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consultaSql);
        sqlArtistaId.setString(1, artistaVO.getNombreArtista());
        ResultSet resultado=sqlArtistaId.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(id);
        while(resultado.next()){
            id=resultado.getInt("ArtistId");
        }
        return id;
    }catch(SQLException excepcion){
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
  }
```

Se cual es el error ya que al crear `artistaVO` estoy creando un artista que está vacío y por lo tanto el nombre que me da está en blanco. El problema es que no sé cómo adaptar este método para que me obtenga el nombre que recojo desde otro método en otra clase.
Este es el método que uso para obtener el nombre:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
    if(evento.getSource()==botonAdd){
        try{
            AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
            AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();
            ArtistaVO artistaVO=new ArtistaVO();

            **albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
            String nombreArtista=elegirArtista.getSelectedItem().toString();
            artistaVO.setNombreArtista(nombreArtista);  **          
            albumDAO.addAlbum(albumVO);
        }catch(Exception excepcion){
            excepcion.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al añadir Album","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
   }
```

He puesto en negrita la parte que recoge el nombre, como he dicho, este método se encuentra en otra clase totalmente distinta.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1**

Este es el método que debe usar `getIdArtista()`:

```
  public void addAlbum(AlbumVO albumVO){

    Conexion conexion=new Conexion();

    try{
        String consultaSql="INSERT into album values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement sqlAddAlbum=conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consultaSql);
        sqlAddAlbum.setInt(1, getMaxIdAlbum());
        sqlAddAlbum.setString(2, albumVO.getNombreAlbum());
        sqlAddAlbum.setInt(3, getIdArtista());
        Integer filasAfectadas=sqlAddAlbum.executeUpdate();

        if(filasAfectadas>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha insertado el Album correctamente","Informacion",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha insertado el Album", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        sqlAddAlbum.close();
        conexion.cerrarConexion();
    }catch(SQLException excepcion){
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha añadido el Album", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, aparentemente es que dentro del método getIdArtista creas el Objeto ArtistaVO artistaVO=new ArtistaVO(); y lógicamente este está en blanco porque es un objeto nuevo.

Una solución para no modificar tu código sería enviar como parámetro el objeto que necesitas a getIdArtista:

```
 public int getIdArtista(final ArtistaV0 artistaV0){

     Conexion conexion=new Conexion();

     int id=0;

     try{
         String consultaSql="SELECT ArtistId from artist where Name=?";
         PreparedStatement sqlArtistaId=conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consultaSql);
         sqlArtistaId.setString(1, artistaVO.getNombreArtista());
         ResultSet resultado=sqlArtistaId.executeQuery();
         System.out.println(id);
         while(resultado.next()){
            id=resultado.getInt("ArtistId");
         }
         return id;
     }catch(SQLException excepcion){
         excepcion.printStackTrace();
         return 0;
     }
   }
```

Aunque me da la sensación de que el método getIdArtista forma parte del objeto ArtistaV0. Si es así yo separaría la lógica de la carga jdbc del objeto POJO ArtistaV0.

Realmente el código de la función getIdArtista quedaría simple:

```
public int getIdArtista() {

    return this.idArtista;

}
```

Y el método de carga lo haría en una clase tipo Dao:

```
public final class ArtistaDao {

    public int findIdByName(final String nombreArtista){

        Conexion conexion=new Conexion();

        int id=0;

        try{
            String consultaSql="SELECT ArtistId from artist where Name=?";
            PreparedStatement sqlArtistaId=conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consultaSql);
            sqlArtistaId.setString(1, nombreArtista);
            ResultSet resultado=sqlArtistaId.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(id);
            while(resultado.next()){
               id=resultado.getInt("ArtistId");
            }
            return id;
        }catch(SQLException excepcion){
           excepcion.printStackTrace();
           return 0;
        }

      }

}
```

Comment: He actualizado mi post con el método que toma el valor que da `getIdArtista()` ; `getIdArtista()` está ya dentro de una clase DAO, junto con `addAlbum()` por lo tanto pasando `ArtistaVO` como parametro me da error en la llamada en `addAlbum()` lo subraya en rojo, espero que ahora se entienda mejor mi problema.

Comment: Entiendo que el problema es el mismo, cuando llamas a sqlAddAlbum.setInt(3, getIdArtista()); dentro de getIdArtista creas el objeto ArtistaVO artistaVO=new ArtistaVO(); si después haces sqlArtistaId.setString(1, artistaVO.getNombreArtista()); el nombre del artista estará en blanco porque acabas de crearlo como un objeto nuevo. A no ser que haya algo que se me escapa. ¿Por cierto en que objeto esta el método addAlbum?

Comment: Se que el problema es al crear el objeto `ArtistaVO` dentro de `getIdArtista()` ya que lo crea vacio, por eso mi problema es que no se como hacer para que ese método coja el nombre que le paso en `actionPerformed()` porque si paso `ArtistaVO` como parametro para `getIdArtista()` me da error en la llamada que hago en ´addAlbum()´.
`addAlbum` pertenece a una clase que se llama `AlbumDAO` la cual también incluye `getIdArtista()`

Comment: Disculpa a ver si lo entiendo: Si pones  en el actionPerformed albumDAO.addAlbum(albumVO,artistaV0); y cambias el  método por public void addAlbum(AlbumV0 albumV0, ArtistaV0 artistaV0) entiendo que te da error. ¿Que tipo de error?

Comment: Disculpa, era culpa mia, no estaba pasando `ArtistaVO` como parametro en todos los sitios que debía, ahora ya funciona a la perfección. ¡Muchas gracias!